# Why I am getting attribute error in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When I run this ,

```
nfl_frame.columns
```

then , I have this output:

```
Index(['Rank ', 'Team ', 'Won ', 'Lost ', 'Tied* ', 'Pct. ', 'First Season ',
       'Total Games ', 'Conference'],
      dtype='object')
```

But, when I write :

```
nfl_frame.Rank
```

it shows the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-49fcdc59c710> in <module>()
----> 1 nfl_frame.Rank

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2148                 return self[name]
   2149             raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
-> 2150                                  (type(self).__name__, name))
   2151 
   2152     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Rank'
```

*I am using Python 3.4 and Ipython notebook.

Comment: The column name `'Rank '` has a space after it, so a dotted lookup won't work. Use `nfl_frame['Rank ']` instead, or strip the spaces off the column names.

Comment: Yeah....it worked.... when I use nfl_frame['Rank '] , with a space, then it worked.  Thanks.